# Do the sample space ($\Omega$) and the $\sigma$-algebra ($\mathcal{F}$) of a probability space form a topology space?

Tags: probability, general-topology, measure-theory

[I realize that this question may be too basic and likely to contain a fundamental misunderstanding, but similar questions such as [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1330649/152225) on the site are beyond my math level. So please assume very limited understanding of measure theory. If at all possible an answer in plain English would be ideal.]

---

A [probability space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_space#Definition) is defined as the triple ($\Omega,\mathcal{F},P$).

The sample space and the sigma-algebra of events of a probability space -($\Omega,\mathcal{F}$)- would seem to fulfill the [conditions of a topological space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space#Open_set_definition), ($X,\tau$):

1. There is always a null event ($P(\{\emptyset\} = 0)$) and a certain event ($P(\{\Omega\})=1$). This corresponds to the condition, "The empty set and $X$ itself belong to $\tau$" in a topology sapce.
2. Any union of events belongs to $\mathcal{F}$ (closed under countable unions). The counterpart in topology spaces: "Any (finite or infinite) union of members of $\tau$ still belongs to $\tau$."
3. The intersection of any number of events belongs to $\mathcal{F}$ (closed under countable intersections). In topology spaces: "The intersection of any finite number of members of $\tau$ still belongs to $\tau$."

Can we then say that the sample space $\Omega$ and the $\sigma$-algebra, ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}$), form a topology on $\Omega$?

I believe that ($\Omega, \mathcal{F}$) also fulfills the conditions of a measurable space, so I may be indirectly asking the difference between a topological and a [measurable space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)#Definition).

Is the coincidence of criteria an accident among conceptually disparate mathematical objects: probability (or measurable) spaces v. topology spaces?

Is it just a matter of the geometric component of topology?

Intuitively, I see that when applying a function to these spaces, in the case of topology we may want to relate somehow subsets by proximity; and I can see how in assigning a probability measure in [0,1] to different events, the result will be similar the more related (closer?) these events are...

---

Post-mortem notes:

- In a $\sigma$-algebra any [**countable union**](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/628045/152225) of elements in  $\mathcal{F}$ have to be contained in  $\mathcal{F}$. On the other hand for a topological space it is **any arbritrary union (finite or infinite) of the elments of the topology** $\tau$ has to be contained in $\tau$.      $\sim \text{Comment 1 below.}$
- By De Morgan's law and closure under complements of probability spaces, $\mathcal{F}$ is similary closed under **countable intersections**. Conversely, in topology it is the **intersection of finite** elements of $\tau$ that remains contained in $\tau$.

Comment: "Any union of events belongs to F" Nope, only countable ones. This is the reason why not every topology is a sigma-algebra.

Comment: An example of what goes wrong: the sigma-algebra of Borel sets (or even Lebesgue-measurable sets) on $\Bbb R$ contains all the singletons $\{x\}$, $x\in\Bbb R$. The only topology on $\Bbb R$ (or any set) that contains the singletons is the discrete one.

Comment: @Did Well, I had a feeling that it wouldn't be correct... No Google returns is always an ominous sign... Your point seems to offer a single differentiating feature, and it'd be great if you could unfold it into an answer for dummies...

Comment: Unfold into what? I feel mine and @G.Sassatelli's comment together pretty much sum up what there is to understand to the matter (whether for "dummies" or not).

Comment: Also, $99\%$ of well-behaved topologies are not closed under complementation, while this is a crucial feature of sigma-algebra. To be fair, both in geometry and analysis we are particular fond of *connected* topological spaces, i.e. topological spaces $(X,\tau)$ where the only $A\subseteq X$ such that $A\in\tau\wedge X\setminus A\in\tau$ are $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, topologies and measurable spaces are not the same notions ; some topologies on a set are not measurable spaces and some measurable spaces on a set are not topologies.

A topology $T$ usually generates a measurable space $M$ called the *Borel $\sigma$-algebra*, which is the smallest $\sigma$-algebra containing all open sets, i.e. containing the topology. We have $T=M$ if and only if $T$ is a measurable space, i.e. if and only if $T$ is closed under countable intersections ; this can happen but there are lots of counter-examples (for instance, topological manifolds).

A measurable space $M$ is a topology if and only if it is closed under *arbitrary unions*, not just countable ones. For instance, if we take an uncountable set $X$ and let $Y \subseteq X$ satisfy $Y \in M$ if and only if $Y$ or $X \backslash Y$ is countable, this defines a $\sigma$-algebra $M$ on $X$. It is not a topology because $X$ admits a subset $Y$ which is uncountable with uncountable complement and we can write $Y = \bigcup_{y \in Y} \{y\}$ (a union of subsets in $M$ which does not belong to $M$).

Hope that helps,

Comment: It's great, but I wish you had (if possible) dumbed it down a bit, steering away from set-based definitions.

Comment: @AntoniParellada You are asking a somewhat technical question about the distinction between two mathematical objects which are defined in terms of set operations. I'm afraid there isn't any "dumbing down," step #1 in math is always to learn the language :)

Comment: Of course... Sometimes people ask for a "motivating example" or an "intuition"...

Comment: @Antoni Parellada : I assure you that your question *is* set-based. The amount of set-theory I used is not hard, I kept it to a minimum. For instance, the measurable space I introduced is the smallest one needed to introduce the *counting  measure* ; i.e. the one whose value on a finite set is the number of its elements. Feel free to ask for me details but I assure you this is the answer you want ; it gives you the distinction between the axioms of a topological space and those of a measurable space.